# How to change the primary key for a EntityData derived class default string Id property to an int property?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6, azure-mobile-services

I recently started to learn about Azure Mobile Services, I followed [this tutorial](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-windows-store-dotnet-leaderboard/) about it and the classes for my model are required to inherit from the EntityData class.

From the [EntityData source code](http://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Metadata/NuGet/Project/WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Backend.Entity/1.0.195-beta/Release/.NETFramework,Version=v4.5/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service.Entity/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service.Entity/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service.Entity/EntityData.cs), an Id property is already defined to act as a primary key, but it is defined as string which doesn't work for my Model that uses int.

My class looks like this:

```
public partial class Role : EntityData
{
    public Role()
    {
        this.Users = new HashSet<User>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

If I try to use this class, I get an error message saying an Id property is already defined.

Is there a way to define a different property as a primary key? In case this change is not possible, is there a way to use this string Id property as an incremental primary key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution is to use automapper. Here's a blog post that outlines how to do it, essentially you store an int, but transform it into a string when it is sent over the wire:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/azuremobile/archive/2014/05/22/tables-with-integer-keys-and-the-net-backend.aspx

Comment: wow, it was a lot simpler than I thought,but how do I set it to be auto incrementable? Mostly because when I try not to send it I get the error message stating the Id property is required.

Comment: A quick question, the example in that page you shared deals with an entity with a primary key, but in case I'm dealing with one having both a primery key and foregin key(s), do I have to map for each one of them with their DTO string equivalent in my WebApiConfig class?

Comment: Ideally, yes. Alternatively, you can use Automapper to flatten the relationship.